# Android r8b c++ shared library problems

Tags: android, c++, shared, gcc4.7

This is a weird setup here. I compiled a custom NDK with GCC 4.7 (for Debian armhf chroot host). In testing, it compiles and runs regular c and c++ binaries on Android perfectly. When trying to compile a test shared library with C++ using:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -fPIC -shared test.cpp -lstdc++ -o test.so
```

I get numerous linker errors to `_staticinitialization_destruction` and `_dso_handle` being unreferenced.

I have both `libstdc++.a` and `libstdc++.so` available in the lib folder under `arm-linux-androideabi` directory. What is going on? There's hardly any info on Android C++ standalone compiling out there.

*Edit*
It seems __dso_handle is undefined for the iostream portion of the GNU STL. I found the answer from a 2005 Linux post. Still an issue in 2012 it seems :O lol.